Isn't this relation NOT antisymmetric?
$$
R=\left\{x{,}\ y\in\mathbb{R}:\ y^2=1-x^{ }\right\}
$$
Since (0,1) and (1,0) satisfy this relation and $1 \ne 0$, am I correct in saying that this relation is actually NOT antisymmetric?
There was a quiz in a course I was taking asking if the above is antisymmetric (true or false), I answered false and was marked as wrong. I brought this up with course support explaining why I think my answer is correct, and was given the following explanation for why my answer was wrong -

Relation R is antisymmetrical, if from $y^2=1-x$ and $x^2=1-y$ follows that x=y. Or: if $y^2=1-x$ and $x\ne y$, then $x^2\ne1-y$
domain: $y^2=1-x\ge0\implies x\le1$
So: $y^2=1-x\implies x=1-y^2\implies x^2=\left(1-y^2\right)^2=1-y$
$\left(1-y^2\right)^2=1-y$ holds, only when (y=0, y=1), so relation R is not symmetrical.
Correct answer: True


Yes, you are correct. What is the context of your question?

To be perfectly clear, are you certain that you copied the problem correctly?  It is possible that the question author had actually written or at least intended to write that $x,y\in\Bbb R^*$ or something similar which would have excluded one of $0$ or $1$ from the domain at which point the quoted explanation would make sense and be conclusive and correct.

Yes, it is exactly as displayed.

The quoted "solution" is bizarre.  While most the steps are correct, the ending is wrong in multiple ways.
First, it is true that if there exists $x,y$ such that both $y^2 = 1-x$ and $x^2 = 1-y$, then this would imply $$(1-y^2)^2 = 1-y. \tag{1}$$  But then it claims that the only solutions to this equation are $y \in \{0, 1\}$, which is plainly incorrect:  note
$$\begin{align}
0 &= (1-y^2)^2 - (1-y) \\
&= (1-y)^2 (1+y)^2 - (1-y) \\
&= (1-y)((1-y)(1+y)^2 - 1) \\
&= (1-y)(y - y^2 - y^3) \\
&= y(1-y)(1 - y - y^2). \tag{2}
\end{align}$$
Thus there are two additional roots, namely $$y = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2} = \{-\varphi, -1/\varphi\}, \tag{3}$$ where $\varphi = (1+\sqrt{5})/2$ is the golden ratio.
However, this is immaterial to the second error, which is the claim that $R$ is not symmetric because of the existence of these solutions.  One would have to complete the logic; i.e., if $y^2 = 1-x$ and $x^2 = 1-y$, then the complete solution set must be characterized:
$$(x,y) \in \left\{(1,0), (0,1), (-\varphi, -\varphi), (-1/\varphi, -1/\varphi)\right\}. \tag{4}$$
Only in the last two cases does it follow that $x = y$.  In the first two cases, we see that $x \ne y$.
Finally, the assertion that "$R$ is not symmetric" is true, but that is not what the question asked for, because "not symmetric" does not mean the same thing as "antisymmetric."  A symmetric relation implies that for all $(x,y) \in R$, then $(y,x) \in R$.  That's not true here, so $R$ is indeed not symmetric.  But to then say that this means $R$ is antisymmetric is plainly wrong.

If you mean that
$$
R = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y^2 = 1-x \}
$$
(which establishes $R$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ and not simply a subset of $\mathbb{R}$), then yes. The pairs $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ both lie in $R$.
However, if $R$ was antisymmetric, we would know that if, whenever $(a,b),(b,a) \in R$, it is actually the case that $a=b$.
Since $0 \ne 1$, then $R$ is definitely not antisymmetric.
